# When disconnect or refresh Django channels websocket "took too long to shut down and was killed"

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am using Django Channel for a real-time sending and saving data but when I refresh the page the error came up. I don't know why but, on first load the system is okay but if I reload the page the log appears.

log

```
Application instance <Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<StaticFilesWrapper.__call__() running at path\channels\staticfiles.py:44> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]>> for connection <WebSocketProtocol client=['127.0.0.1', 50991] path=b'/ws/graph/'> took too long to shut down and was killed.
```

consumer.py

```
    async def connect(self):
          event= eventhubreader.EventReader()
          async def cb(partition, events):
            data = events[len(events)-1]
            mock = event.generateMockData(data.body_as_json())
            await self.send(json.dumps(mock))
          
        await self.accept()
        while True:
            await event.startReadMessage("HostName","name",cb)
```

evenhubreader.py

```
 def generateMockData(self,event):
        data = {}
        now = datetime.now()
        data["temperature"]  = random.randint(23,25)
        data["tss"]  = random.randint(5,8)
        data["vss"]  = random.randint(1,4)
        data["bod"]  = random.randint(1,7)
        data["doc"]  = random.randint(8,13)
        data["cod"]  = random.randint(5,12)
        data["ph"]  = random.randint(2,13)
        data["turbidity"]  = random.randint(1,5)
        data["conductivity"]  = random.randint(1,7)
        data['datetime'] = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        return data
```

requirements.txt

```
arrow==1.2.2
asgiref==3.5.2
azure-core==1.24.2
azure-eventhub==5.10.0
azure-iot-device==2.11.0
azure-iot-hub==2.6.0
channels==3.0.5
cryptography==37.0.4
daphne==3.0.2
Django==4.1
django-crispy-forms==1.14.0
pandas==1.4.3
pendulum==2.1.2
pipreqs==0.4.11
plotly==5.9.0
psycopg2==2.9.3
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.21
pydantic==1.9.1
PyJWT==2.4.0
pyOpenSSL==22.0.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
PyPika==0.48.9
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.20.0
python-engineio==4.3.3
python-slugify==6.1.2
python-socketio==5.7.1
websockets==10.3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just my guess, I think the while is not terminated, so try to terminate the while when it is disconnected.

```py
async def connect(self):
    await self.accept()
    self.event_close = False
    while not self.event_close:
        await event.startReadMessage("HostName","name",cb)

async def disconnect(self, close_code):
    self.event_close = True
```